# Show Image When page is Loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a mobile application using jquery mobile. Now, I am trying to load an image whenever page is loading. I want to hide the default page loading image and message and instead I want to load external image. Besides, Whenever a page is loading the image, I want to hide the background(page contents) as well.

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have tried $j.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); 
 $j('body').addClass('ui-loading');

Answer (score 0):

I would look at spin.js http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

Run the spinner while the page is loading, then

```
.spin(false)
```

To stop it.

Comment: No Connor. its not working. Still it loads the default page loading image

Answer (score 0):

use this method.

```
$.mobile.loading( 'show', {
    text: 'foo',
    textVisible: true,
    theme: 'z',
    html: ""
})
```

here is more description [jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/loader.html)

Comment: Nope.still its not working. It loads the default image whenever the page is loading. I think we have to overwrite .ui-loader{ } in the JQM.

Comment: @ThiyagarajanSelvaraj you have to use custom html
`<button class="show-page-loading-msg" data-theme="a" data-textonly="true" data-textvisible="true" data-msgtext="Custom Loader" data-icon="arrow-r" data-html="<span class='ui-bar ui-overlay-c ui-corner-all'><img src='YOUR IMAGE LINK' /><h2>is loading for you ...</h2></span>" data-iconpos="right">Custom HTML</button>`